# Any way to make file resource forks uncopyable by Finder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icons, macos-carbon, nsworkspace

Is there any way to make resource forks uncopyable? In particular I'm setting a custom badge icon to the files contained in a specific directory through NSWorkspace via `– setIcon:forFile:options:` and I'd like those badges to be lost as soon as the files gets copied outside the folder.

Comment: For the Dropbox-side of the thing it looks like they go with mach-star code injection into the Finder process. Which is a thing I'd rather avoid if possible.

Comment: Dropbox is not using code injection on Leopard.

Comment: I am looking solution for leopard.

Comment: @jennifer not sure I understand, you first ask how to make resource fork uncopyable, then you go on talking about DropBox getting a KILL signal... where is the connection ? what do you mean with the Dropbox reference ?

Comment: @Yahia dropbox is also using custom icon in leopard os and when we quit dropbox application they are removing custom icon.

Comment: @Yahia There is no connection between resource fork uncopyable and dropbox getting kill signle. i am just looking answer for how to make file resource fork uncopyable.

Comment: @jennifer please see my answer below... if you need to this server-side then please provide more information on the server platform...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no easy/standard way to make that happen...

IF the filesystems we are talking about are based locally on the the Mac itself then you can achieve what you want by implementing a daemon (running with high priviliges). This daemon basically integrates itself into the OS (via both FSEvent and kqueue) - this way it can monitor any file activity and act accordingly (remove the badge or similar).

For some source on how to build such a mechanism you can check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FileNotification/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003143-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289) and [this too](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW1-SW1).

IF you want to achieve this server-side there are several mechanisms - but they solely depend on the server technology (an notification and/or hooking mechanism).

Comment: I think this is a pretty good aproach although I'm wondering whether the kqueue aproach is too heavy when the file hierarchy is too deep.

Comment: I mean, you have to know where the file gets copied to and remove the badge from there.

Comment: @AlessandroDiaferia I agree that this can have a performance impact but this is the only approach I know of except for injecting some code at runtime into the OS processes (which I would not recommend). As for how to know where it gets copied there might a "radical solution" - the badge you assign is a unique one you can recognize thus you could just check on file creation whether it has this badge and remove if it outside the "source folders".

Comment: @AlessandroDiaferia basically yes... you could perhaps lessen the performance impact if you integrate with the Spotlight services (there some ways to hook into that) since they already get these notifications you need...

Comment: well, although this is a cleaner way I think swizzling into Finder code works better at this point. At least it feels less heavy on the whole system.

Comment: @AlessandroDiaferia it might be less heavy BUT it doesn't catch all filesystem operations AND it is harder to support since it might fail/bring the finder down with any OS update... thus for internal use perhaps the Finder injection is ok but IMHO not recommended for production use...

Comment: I agree but as long as Apple doesn't provide a "right" way to plug-in Finder... Also, if what you want to do is limited to just a specific folder (like the Dropbox case), you do not need to do FS Events monitoring at all.

Comment: @AlessandroDiaferia you can configure FSEvent monitoring to a specific folder... BTW: DropBox comes AFAIK with an FSEvent monitoring daemon for exactly this purpose

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6526/discussion-between-alessandro-diaferia-and-yahia)

Comment: @AlessandroDiaferia ok - I am there

Comment: I know FSEvent can be configured for whatever folder you want but the thing is still the same. If you're monitoring a folder you do not know the destination of the file you are copying outside that folder. That's why I say swizzling still is the "right" way to go if you are working on just one folder. Dropbox makes use of FSEvents to know when to sync your folder with the cloud but uses swizzling to show badges on your files.